# Convert ISO8601 date to epoch format (unix timestamp)

Tags: javascript, date, converters, unix-timestamp, iso8601

How do I convert ISO 8601 date (ex. 20140107) to Unix timestamp (ex. 1389120125) using javascript?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a browser with ECMAscript 5 support, [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) accepts an ISO-8601 datestring and returns an  epoch value in milliseconds, so just divide that by 1000 and you're done.

#### However

Contrary to what you state, your input string doesn't conform to the [ISO-8601 subset defined in ECMAscript](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15) because it's lacking the dashes between the individual fields.  As far as I know, the dashes are mandatory for EMCAscript (even though ISO 8601 itself allows the dashless, or basic, format).  So maybe you'll have to do some string parsing and use one of Date's constructors and its [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method to obtain the same

```
new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

If you want to remain compatible with older browsers but still use Date.parse, you could consider including [this shim](https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `Date.parse(20140107);` and got `NaN`. Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: @Steve that's exactly the issue I tried to explain in my answer, plus a bonus one: you have to pass that variable as a string, otherwise it will be seen as a number.  ***However*** Javascript ***does not*** support the basic, dash-less representation of dates meaning that `Date.parse("2014-01-07")` will work whereas `Date.parse("20140107")` won't.  If you're stuck with the latter some string parsing will be required.